# I want to combine two queries in which second query is to be repeated

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have two parts in a query having first part as constant and second part as repeating based on some condition. What I want it to get all the query as a string and execute at the end.

I have written a query for the first part but it's also not giving any output it returns as 0 rows returned

```
SET @Origindate = '2016-06-01';
SET @Startdate = (SELECT(DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(sysdate()),INTERVAL 1 DAY)));
SET @firstpart = "SELECT 
    fullname,dc.mail,
    CASE
        WHEN x,y,z
        AND month(dc.buyingDate) < month((@buyingdate) -11) 
        AND month(dc.buyingDate) >= month((@buyingdate) -12)";
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @firstpart ;
EXECUTE stmt1 OUT ;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1; 
SET @secondpart = "()";
```

I need result which is something like this(firstpart + (1st repeating part + 2nd repeating part +...so on untill the condition is fulfilled). And what I am getting is blank.

Comment: @firstpart does not contain a valid sql statement so I would not expect it to return anything when executed.

Comment: @P.Salmon  can you please tell me where is the issue in the          
 firstpart except the Date and date that is just because I missed typed it.

Comment: @firstpart looks like this SELECT 
    fullname,dc.mail,
    CASE
        WHEN x,y,z
        AND month(dc.buyingDate) < month((@buyingdate) -11) 
        AND month(dc.buyingDate) >= month((@buyingdate) -12) - the case statement is invalid because it is missing a then statement an action if true and an end statement.(i'm not not convinced about the when clause either) also where are the columns fullname,dc.mail coming from , there is no from clause.